# Print index of sublists with error?

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

I have a list that is made up of sublists of a certain length, kind of like `[["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d","e"]]`. What I want to do is find the index of the sublist that does not have that certain length, and then print that index out. For example, in the example list, the last sublist does not have a length of four, so I would print `list 2 does not have correct length`. This is what I have so far:

```
for i in newlist:
    if len(i) == 4:
        print("okay")
elif len(i) != 4:
    ind = i[0:]     #this isnt finished; this prints out the lists with the not correct length, but not their indecies 
    print("not okay",ind)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you want both the index and the object, you can often use `enumerate`, which yields `(index, element)` tuples.  For example:

```
>>> seq = "a", "b", "c"
>>> enumerate(seq)
<enumerate object at 0x102714eb0>
>>> list(enumerate(seq))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

and so:

```
newlist = [["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d","e"]]

for i, sublist in enumerate(newlist):
    if len(sublist) == 4:
        print("sublist #", i, "is okay")
    else:
        print("sublist #", i, "is not okay")
```

produces

```
sublist # 0 is okay
sublist # 1 is okay
sublist # 2 is not okay
```

Comment: This really helped! Thanks! Just wondering, is there a way to not have the object, only the index?

Comment: You need to have the object to take its length, though.  You could use `for i in range(len(newlist)):` and then `newlist[i]`, but that's considered unpythonic style.

Answer (score 0):

I think DSM got the answer you were after, but you could also use the [index method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.index) and write something like the following:

```
new_list = [["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d"],["a","b","c","d","e"]]
size_filter = 4
# all values that are not 4 in size
indexes = [new_list.index(val) for val in new_list if len(val)!=size_filter]
# output values that match
for index in indexes:
    print("{0} is not the correct length".format(index))
```